# How I can run my NUnit test with Selenium WebDriver using MSBuild + bath?

Tags: c#, batch-file, selenium, msbuild, nunit

I have a few simple NUnit tests with Selenium WebDriver in my VS. How I can run my tests in console using MSBuild + batch? I create .bat file the following:

```
set pathMSBuild = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\"
@echo off
cls
cd %pathMSBuild%
msbuild.exe "C:\Users\IliA\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GitHubAutomation\GitHubAutomation.sln" /p:configuration=debug
pause
```

But when I try to run build.bat I have an error: 'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

My build.bat is situated in a C:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable msbuild in Command Prompt, **pls add .Net(version) framework location to the PATH environment variable.**

Environment variables can be accessed by right clicking on 'Computer', select 'properties', click 'Advanced system settings' on the left nav. In the dialog box click 'Environment variables' button and update 'PATH'with .Net framework path for e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.

**or**

Update your bat file to CD into .Net framework directory where msbuild.exe is available and then issue `msbuild <prj>` command as shown below:

```
CD C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
msbuild <<YOUR PROJECT PATH>>
PAUSE
EXIT
```